# Get flag emoji/string from country code with 3 letters

Tags: swift, emoji

I have an array of countries which provides me country code in 3 letters([ISO 3166-1 alpha-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) country code).

For eg. "USA" for United States of America

I have a method which can give me flag emoji/string from 2 letters i.e. "US" not "USA".

Below method works for 2 letters country code but won't work for 3 letters.

```
func flag(countryCode: String) -> String? {
    var string = ""
    let country = countryCode.uppercased()

    let regionalA = "".unicodeScalars
    let letterA = "A".unicodeScalars
    let base = regionalA[regionalA.startIndex].value - letterA[letterA.startIndex].value

    for scalar in country.unicodeScalars {
        guard let regionalScalar = UnicodeScalar(base + scalar.value) else { return nil }
        string.unicodeScalars.append(regionalScalar)
    }
    return string.isEmpty ? nil : string
}
```

How can I achieve flag from 3 letter country code?

Comment: You could use the 3-letter codes as keys for a dictionary with the 2-letter codes as values.

Comment: @Magnas Yes that could be done but I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: The flags are (apparently) based on the two-letter (alpha-2) country code, so your actual question is “How to convert a three-letter country code to a two-letter code?”

Comment: @MartinR Yes. I know by mapping 3 letter with 2 letter code and then get an emoji but I am looking if any native solution available.

Answer (score 0):

Write a translation collection that holds all CountryCode translations. In this object I would put 2 fields or properties. One would be the tripleCountryCode prop/field and the other would be something like a dualCountryCode prop/field...

O.C. you would have to enter every code that has to be translated manually like so:
(I am putting Typescript since it is my main coding language and it looks similar to your code, so maybe you can use it...)

**Typescript Code**

```
// We take an interface as the object declaration
export interface TranslatedCountryCode {
  tripleCode: string;
  dualCode: string;
}

// We set up a class to handle the translations
export class TranslationClass {
  static translations: TranslatedCountryCode[] = [
    { tripleCode: "USA", dualCode: "US" },
    { tripleCode: "GER", dualCode: "DE" },
    { tripleCode: "GBR", dualCode: "GB" } // And so on....
  ];
  static GetDualTranslation(tripleCode: string): string | null {
    for (var key in this.translations)
      // If we find something we return it....
      if (tripleCode === this.translations[key].tripleCode)
        return this.translations[key].dualCode;
      // If we don't find any translation we return null....
    return null;
  }
  static GetTripleTranslation(dualCode: string): string | null {
    for (var key in this.translations)
      // If we find something we return it....
      if (dualCode === this.translations[key].dualCode)
        return this.translations[key].tripleCode;
    // If we don't find any translation we return null....
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then you simply can call a translation like so:

```
TranslationClass.GetDualTranslation("USA") // Returns US

TranslationClass.GetTripleTranslation("US") // Returns USA
```

Please give this Post a thumbs up if it helped you, I would appreciate it very much.

Kind Regards

**Edit** : I noticed you can o.c. also take a dictionary but then you would have to double enter every translation in to the triplecode dict and the dualcode dictionary... I solved it with the for loop to avoid the double assignment.